# Materials "stuck" in the Materials Editor

Tags: materials, workflow

How do I get rid of these two materials that apparently "stuck" in the materials tab? I've tried the "CLEAN SLOT" menu item, I've tried the unlink "fake user", I've tried deleting the NODE's in the NODE Editor. They won't go away ... ;-(

Thanks
RonK95
[image]

Comment: Did you try to save and open the file again? Have you check the Orphan data in the outliner?

Comment: yes, select the material you want to delete, shift and click the "X" button, then reopen the file... or, after shift X, go into the Outliner window, select Orphan Data, then click on the top right button called "Purge All"

Comment: Thanks Leander and moonboots.  That did the trick.  I didn't even know about the orphan data tab.  Good to know.